# Windows 2008 server installation asks for Hard Drive Drivers in Dell Power edge sc1420

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, dell-poweredge, drivers

We are having blue screen from windows 2008 server, even with Safe Mode, so we are trying to repair the OS, but it keeps asking for HD Drivers, we have a Maxtor 6L160M0 (Pretty old, I know) and we are not able to find the firmware for the windows installation anywhere, do you have some advice, or how can we fix this problem we are facing right now?

Our server is "Dell Poweredge sc1420" (Service Tag: 8HBN691)

This is the process I did so far:

- Boot from Windows 2008 Server DVD
- Click on Repair my Computer
- There's a screen here that tells me to load the partitions (Nothing listed)
- I click on the option load drivers

I've tried with all these from an USB Flash Drive:

[Drivers From Dell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS933.png)

And some old drivers from Maxtor/Seagate with no success

Comment: More than likely it's looking for the drivers for the hard drive controller, not the hard drives. Have you looked on the Dell support site for the appropriate drivers?

Comment: Yes I did, and loaded a lot of them, still not luck at all @joeqwerty

Comment: How did you load them, and which items did you load? You have to be more specific if you expect any help. When anybody else looks at this, the first thing we think is - this is simple. So, unless you can tell us step by step what you did and tried we won't be able to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @Appleoddity edited and updated the question

Comment: Please specify the service tag for your server. That is the only way we can look up your exact configuration and drivers. You'll need the "F6-floppy" drivers for your specific controller.

Comment: @Appleoddity it doesn't have a floppy disk drive, just CD ROM and USB slots, I am using the USB flash drive to load the drivers, our server is Dell Poweredge sc1420

Comment: That is what the drivers are called on Dell's website. Download the "floppy" version then extract the files and put them on your USB drive. I can see them on dell's website. Without the service tag I don't know what exact hardware you have.

Comment: You have to click on "view full driver details."

Comment: @Appleoddity the service tag is 8HBN691

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and decompress the following files to your USB drive to load drivers from.

If you have 64-bit Windows:

- https://downloads.dell.com/SATA/R126742.EXE
- https://downloads.dell.com/SATA/R111014.EXE

If you have 32-bit Windows:

- https://downloads.dell.com/SATA/R168588_A8.exe
- https://downloads.dell.com/SATA/R126743.EXE

You may have multiple controllers / versions to choose from once you load drivers from the USB. You may have to go through them until you find the one that works.